# Binary tree optimize solution?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, depth-first-search

Got this problem in one of the coding contest . Do you have a better approach than mine . I have given the pseudocode below

Given a complete binary tree with nodes of values of either 1 or 0, the following rules always hold:

1. a node's value is 1 if and only if all its subtree nodes' values are 1
2. a leaf node can have value either 1 or 0

Implement the following 2 APIs:

- `set_bit(offset, length)`, set the bits at range from `offset` to `offset+length-1` on the leaf nodes
- `clear_bit(offset, length)`, clear the bits at range from `offset` to `offset+length-1` on the leaf nodes

i.e. The tree is like:

```
             0
          /     \
         0        1
       /  \      /  \
      0    1     1    1
     /\   / \   / \  / \
    0  1 1   1 1  1  1  1
```

Input will given in 2 D array

```
int arr[][] = [ [0],[0,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]]
```

we need to set the bit or clear bit on the leaf nodes. In the above example if I do

`clear(3,5)`

```
i.e. The tree would be like:
             0
          /     \
         0        0
       /  \      /  \
      0    0     0   0
     /\   / \   / \  / \
    0  1 1   0 0   0 0  0
```

Pseudocode : My approach

1] Go to the last row and inner loop starts at offset on the leaf node (last row + offset).

2] check for the element at the offset if it is 1

3] if sibling zero the ancestor is zero no further action else if it is one

4] note down the range of the ancestor to zero in our case 
(ancestor is row-- and column/2) so in our case for row 2 (range is column 1 to 3)

5]next iteration row 2 and the inner loop  will move from column 1 to 3

6] keep repeating

For set bit as well we can for a similar approach

Comment: I don't get your example. After `clear(3,5)` why do leafs 6 and 7 get cleared?

Comment: @user58697 the offset is 3 and the length to be cleared is 3+5 -1, so index , 3,4,5,6,7 is cleared

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the API. Second argument is length, not an upper limit.